# how to characterize bias from unobserved sub-component variation

Tags: econometrics, panel-data

Let's say I have data at the country-year level -- say, on Gross Domestic Product (GDP) and capital stock (K). I'd like to know the relationship between the two, So I regress GDP_it on K_it and other stuff, and come out with a coefficient that measures the relationship.

But, I have reason to believe there's variation at the sub-national level (say, by industry sector). Unfortunately, I do not have industry sector data on either GDP or K (I observe GDP_it, K_it but not GDP_ijt, K_ijt).

Now I want to characterize the bias in my coefficient that arises from not observing sub-national variation. It seems like I ought to be able to say something about how temporal differences in sector structure (within a country) would affect the estimated relationship. It also seems like this is a well-studied problem, but I haven't been able to find any references on it. Is there a name for this problem, or a general framework for thinking about it?

Comment: Welcome to stat.SE!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  While not necessarily directly related, this looks like the analysis of Beta in reference to stocks and the market in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_(finance)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, @Tavrock. I do not understand the reference to Beta (wrt equities). Can you explain how you see this as being related?

Comment: Admittedly, I am simply thinking out-loud in this case, so I might be really off target.  Beta stocks can be analyzed in their strength in controlling the overall market.  In the US, most Fortune 50 companies have a high Beta.  In the same vein, you may be able to determine the strength of the correlation (and possible impact) from separate industry sectors--possibly even how the stock index for that industry correlates to the GDP or K.

Comment: I still don't see the relation. It seems like you're responding to the question "how is GDP related to capital stock", but that's just an illustrative example. My question is really about how to characterize the bias that results from unobserved variation in nested data -- that is, when the researcher observes the higher-level aggregate but not the lower-level components.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I am answering my own question. I eventually determined that it's best to think about this situation in the context of omitted variables. The omitted variable here is the sub-sector variation; in my setting I was able to make a hypothesis about the direction of the bias from not observing key parts of that variation.